# Flutter large project size on github

Tags: dart, flutter

Folder size is ~250 Mb on github, is there a way to reduce the size?

A friend suggested removing dependencies, is that possible?

***Edit:***

I noticed that the 'build' folder is taking most of the size. Is it okay if I removed it from the repo?

Comment: It sounds like you are committing files that don't belong in version control. Binary/generated files are such things. It is hard to give you any help without details though. Consider posting a link to the repository.

Comment: How did you create the project? If you create with `flutter create ...` a `.gitignore` is created that takes care of files that are not supposed to be committed.

Comment: As @SpencerPark mentions, the `build` folder should never have been committed in the first place. At this point, removing it with another commit will not reduce the repo size because it doesn't remove it from previous commits. I recommend you use [`BFG`](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove the `build` folder, and then force push to the remote repo to overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I opened github and noticed the 'build' folder indeed didn't get pushed. I got confused because my local repo has a large size.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not including the `/build` folder on your repository. Build files can be regenerated using the local copy of the repository. I usually only include these files/folders on my Flutter repo:

```
/android
/assets (if you have an assets folder)
/ios
/lib
/test
/web (if you have web assets)
pubspec.lock
pubspec.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

example of .gitgnore

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.vscode/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Android Studio will place build artifacts here
/android/app/debug
/android/app/profile
/android/app/release
.vscode/launch.json
ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig
ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig
macos/Flutter/Flutter-Debug.xcconfig
macos/Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig
```