# Decreasing the size of the flutter project folder

Tags: flutter, project

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786475/flutter-large-project-size-on-github). but i wanna reduce my project folder size without using git.
**So what do i do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the question refers to a project size optimization - delete all build files (`flutter clean`);
2. If the question refers to an app size optimization - read [Official documentation about app size](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size).

Comment: Thank you! my project size is less than 10MB after `flutter clean`